# Edit HTML Document with Java

Tags: java, html, flying-saucer

I have an HTML document stored in memory (set on a Flying Saucer XHTMLPanel) in my java application.

```
xhtmlPanel.setDocument(Main.class.getResource("/mailtemplate/DefaultMail.html").toString());
```

html file below;

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="first"></p>
        <p id="second"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to set the contents of the `p` elements. I don't want to set a schema for it to use getDocumentById(), so what alternatives do I have?

Comment: I am having a very similar issue, except I am trying to find work-arounds to get getDocumentById() working with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XHTML is XML, so any XML parser would be my recommendataion. I maintain [the JDOM library](http://www.jdom.org), so would naturally recommend using that, but other libraries, including the embedded DOM model in Java will work. I would use something like:

```
    Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(Main.class.getResource("/mailtemplate/DefaultMail.html"));

    // XPath that finds the `p` element with id="first"
    XPathExpression<Element> xpe = XPathFactory.instance().compile(
            "//p[@id='first']", Filters.element());
    Element p = xpe.evaluateFirst(doc);

    p.setText("This is my text");

    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xout.output(doc, System.out);
```

Produces the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head />
  <body>
    <p id="first">This is my text</p>
    <p id="second" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *valid* XHTML is XML. However, most "XHTML" out there is not really valid. For that, I'd recommend a tagsoup solution instead, such as [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid I probably won't get a chance to test this until Monday morning. I'll let you know how it goes and accept your answer if appropriate. I write all my html in valid xhtml format, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

use a fine graded Html parser and manipulation library like [**`jsoup`**](http://jsoup.org/). You can easily create a `Document` by passing the `html` to `jsoup.parse(String htmlContent)` function. This library allows all of the DOM manupulation function including CSS or jquery-like selector syntax. `doc.selct(String selector)`, where `doc` is an instance of `Document`.

For example you can select the first `p` using `doc.select("p").first()`. A minimal working solution would be:

```
Document doc = jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
Element p = doc.select("p").first();
p.text("My Example Text");
```

**Reference:**

1. [Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: Hey Sage, Does it also work when it is a URL? For example: can I replace this href value with other html page.`<a href="https://www.demo.com/login.html" class="login-now" data-cta-name="true" title="top-header:login now">Login Now</a>`