# How to edit/insert new line to html file

Tags: java

I am trying to use following code to edit html page using java.

```
package com.XXX.xxx.xxx

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HTMLReading {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\ItemDetails.html"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if(str.equals("<div id=\"row2\" style=\"display:none;\" ><ul>")) {
                    // add following lines to html
                    //<li><b>Comments</b></li><ul><li>Testing for comment</li></ul>
                }
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }


    }
}
```

On reading perticular line, I want to insert some new line to html.

```
//<li><b>Comments</b></li><ul><li>Testing for comment</li></ul>
```

I tried Append, but it adds the line at end, not at the place where I want.

And my requirement is I have to use only JAVA only for this.

Any thoughts!

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730996/edit-html-document-with-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java.io.BufferedWriter.newLine() method. 
It's non static method, you can find some documantation here: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedwriter_newline.htm

Also, 
You better use StringBuffer and not just String, because it's an immutable object like:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append ("<br>blabla<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
        String str;
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

            if(str.equals("<div id=\"row2\" style=\"display:none;\" ><ul>")) {

                contentBuilder.append("add your content" + str);
            }
            else
            {
                 contentBuilder.append(str);
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

You can store it in a String then write `combined` to the file over what was there.

Comment: You'll be better off with StringBuilder for `combined` rather than plain String.

Comment: @brso05  This fix will work. but my html file will be very huge (contains more than 5000-10000 lines). With this fix, I am rewriting everything back to html. May hit the performace.

Comment: @MIM you should use StringBuilder if it is large file.

Answer (score 0):

Newlines are represented in Java as "\n". It sounds like you want your StringBuilder to contain the contents of the original file, plus the additional lines you describe. To accomplish that your code might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\ItemDetails.html"))) {
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            contentBuilder.append(str);
            if (str.equals("<div id=\"row2\" style=\"display:none;\" ><ul>")) {
                contentBuilder.append("\n<li><b>Comments</b></li><ul><li>Testing for comment</li></ul>\n);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    System.out.println(contentBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: I dont want to have contents of orginal file ,plus the additional lines in StringBuilder. Is there a way we can directly write the additional line to file itself.

Comment: You should update your question to add details of exactly what behavior you are trying to accomplish. Are you saying that you want to overwrite the existing file with one of the given lines for each instance of your search string? If so, then I don't understand why you're complaining that append() adds things onto the end of the string...